# Classification Problem of Four Levels of a Phenomena and not two Using R

Tags: r, classification

I want a better approach to this classification problem. I have four dependent variables, `var1`, `var2`, `var3` and `var4`, each of which is either `TRUE` or `FALSE` to classify whether `var5` belongs to the `0, 1, 2, 3` categories. Here is my data.

```
set.seed(123)
var1 <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=500)
df <- data.frame(var1 = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=500),
                 var2 <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=500),
                 var3 <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=500),
                 var4 <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=500),
                 var5 <- sample(c(0, 1, 2, 3), replace=TRUE, size=500))
```

My attempt is as follows:

```
library(plyr)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(caret)

names <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
dat[,names] <- lapply(dat[,names] , factor)
glimpse(df)

set.seed(100)
library(caTools)

spl = sample.split(df$var5, SplitRatio = 0.7)
train = subset(df, spl==TRUE)
test = subset(df, spl==FALSE)

print(dim(train)); print(dim(test))

#Build, Predict and Evaluate the Model
#To fit the logistic regression model, the first step is to instantiate the algorithm. This is done in the first line of code below with the glm() function. The second line prints the summary of the trained model.

model_glm = glm(var5 ~ . , family="binomial", data = train)
summary(model_glm)
```

**Question**

Please help me to use my data to classify for four levels of a phenomena and not `binary` as I did in my trial?

Answer (score 2):

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(var1 = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=500),
                 var2 = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=500),
                 var3 =sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=500),
                 var4 = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=500),
                 var5 = factor(sample(c(0, 1, 2, 3), replace=TRUE, size=500)))

set.seed(100)
library(caTools)

spl = sample.split(df$var5, SplitRatio = 0.7)
train = subset(df, spl==TRUE)
test = subset(df, spl==FALSE)

print(dim(train)); print(dim(test))

library(nnet)
# Fit the model
fit <- multinom(var5 ~ ., data = train)
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is well received. (1) How do I demonstrate by predicting just a few, let me say, five observations from the fitted model? (2) How do I evaluate the potency of the model? For an instance, `BIC`, `MSE`, `AIC` etc.

Comment: @DanielJames Try `AIC(fit)` and `BIC(fit)`.

Comment: and you can use predict as per normal `predict(fit, newdata = test)`

Answer (score 2):

The code below follows in great part [this (not SO) post](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/ordinal-logistic-regression/).
It fits an ordinal logistic regression model with `MASSS::polr`. It then computes the coefficients' confidence intervals in the odds ratio scale, predicts from the model with the test data set and runs `caret::confusionMatrix` on the predictions.

The `stars.pval` comes from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71952289/8245406)  by SO user [Maël](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13460602/ma%c3%abl).

Note that the data is different, the ordinal response is an **ordered** factor, not a factor like in the question.

```r
set.seed(123)
var1 <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=500)
df <- data.frame(var1 = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=500),
                 var2 = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=500),
                 var3 = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=500),
                 var4 = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=500),
                 var5 = sample(c(0, 1, 2, 3), replace=TRUE, size=500))

df[, 1:4] <- lapply(df[, 1:4] , factor)
df$var5 <- ordered(df$var5)

library(caTools)
library(MASS)

stars.pval <- function(x){
  stars <- c("***", "**", "*", "")
  var <- c(0, 0.01, 0.05, 0.10, 1)
  i <- findInterval(x, var, left.open = T, rightmost.closed = T)
  stars[i]
}

set.seed(100)
spl <- sample.split(df$var5, SplitRatio = 0.7)
train <- subset(df, spl)
test <- subset(df, !spl)

fit <- polr(var5 ~ ., train, Hess = TRUE)
AIC(fit)
#> [1] 980.9098
BIC(fit)
#> [1] 1007.915

ctable <- coef(summary(fit))
## calculate and store p values
p <- pnorm(abs(ctable[, "t value"]), lower.tail = FALSE) * 2

## combined table
(ctable <- cbind(ctable, "p value" = p))
#>             Value Std. Error     t value      p value
#> var11 -0.16090820  0.1921110 -0.83757930 4.022670e-01
#> var21  0.19389705  0.1923504  1.00804088 3.134348e-01
#> var31  0.01078333  0.1932800  0.05579122 9.555081e-01
#> var41 -0.01309085  0.1931528 -0.06777458 9.459651e-01
#> 0|1   -0.94816966  0.2171773 -4.36587776 1.266133e-05
#> 1|2    0.02603120  0.2102911  0.12378653 9.014843e-01
#> 2|3    1.13948524  0.2186379  5.21174533 1.870722e-07
cbind.data.frame(ctable, ` ` = stars.pval(p)) |> print(digits = 5)
#>           Value Std. Error   t value    p value    
#> var11 -0.160908    0.19211 -0.837579 4.0227e-01    
#> var21  0.193897    0.19235  1.008041 3.1343e-01    
#> var31  0.010783    0.19328  0.055791 9.5551e-01    
#> var41 -0.013091    0.19315 -0.067775 9.4597e-01    
#> 0|1   -0.948170    0.21718 -4.365878 1.2661e-05 ***
#> 1|2    0.026031    0.21029  0.123787 9.0148e-01    
#> 2|3    1.139485    0.21864  5.211745 1.8707e-07 ***

ci <- confint(fit)
#> Waiting for profiling to be done...
exp(cbind(OR = coef(fit), ci))
#>              OR     2.5 %   97.5 %
#> var11 0.8513702 0.5838532 1.240404
#> var21 1.2139713 0.8328939 1.771160
#> var31 1.0108417 0.6919196 1.476772
#> var41 0.9869945 0.6757277 1.441490

var5_pred <- predict(fit, newdata = test)
caret::confusionMatrix(test$var5, var5_pred)
#> Confusion Matrix and Statistics
#> 
#>           Reference
#> Prediction  0  1  2  3
#>          0 33  0  0  9
#>          1 31  0  0  3
#>          2 29  0  0  8
#>          3 27  0  0 10
#> 
#> Overall Statistics
#>                                           
#>                Accuracy : 0.2867          
#>                  95% CI : (0.2159, 0.3661)
#>     No Information Rate : 0.8             
#>     P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 1               
#>                                           
#>                   Kappa : 0.0183          
#>                                           
#>  Mcnemar's Test P-Value : NA              
#> 
#> Statistics by Class:
#> 
#>                      Class: 0 Class: 1 Class: 2 Class: 3
#> Sensitivity            0.2750       NA       NA  0.33333
#> Specificity            0.7000   0.7733   0.7533  0.77500
#> Pos Pred Value         0.7857       NA       NA  0.27027
#> Neg Pred Value         0.1944       NA       NA  0.82301
#> Prevalence             0.8000   0.0000   0.0000  0.20000
#> Detection Rate         0.2200   0.0000   0.0000  0.06667
#> Detection Prevalence   0.2800   0.2267   0.2467  0.24667
#> Balanced Accuracy      0.4875       NA       NA  0.55417
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Error when I ran this line: `test <- subset(df, !spl)`
`Error in exists(cacheKey, where = .rs.WorkingDataEnv, inherits = FALSE) : 
  invalid first argument
Error in assign(cacheKey, frame, .rs.CachedDataEnv) : 
  attempt to use zero-length variable name`

Comment: @DanielJames That's a RStudio problem, not the code's. Try terminating and restarting the R session.

Comment: @DanielJames A logical variable does not need an explicit comparison to `FALSE/TRUE` since it already is a logical value, that's why I wrote `test <- subset(df, !spl)`, by negating the false values become true and those rows are chosen by `subset`.